# In Safari/Chrome, how can I trigger a function A on both ready() and focus() and a function B on blur()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a counter that counts down when windows is on focus and stops counting when window is on blur.

My code works perfectly with Firefox and IE because with FF or IE, focus() event is triggered upon load of the document.

But in Safari/Chrome it's not.

Does anyone know how I can trigger the countDown() function upon loading with Safari/Chrome?
Thanks a lot

my code has this structure:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
         $(window).focus(function(){
              countDown();      
          });

       $(window).blur(function(){
              stopCount();      
          });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you call `countDown` from ready aswell? You might have to check if the window still has focus first though. And you should make sure `countDown` wasn't called already - or make countDown "resistant" against additional calls.

Or another way, that should make the code a bit cleaner is to simply call `$(document).focus()` from `$(document).ready`.

More context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).focus(function(){
        countDown();      
    }).blur(function(){
        stopCount();      
    }).focus();
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. both my functions are called from ready. I changed $(document) to $(window) (i edited my post) and now the timer only starts up if I click out of the browser window and focus in again. Regards

Comment: Just set the focus manually by running `$(document).focus();` on load !

Comment: I know, but it did'nt seem to sink in, so I thought it worth repeating!

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your help. The user above found a way that works great with a simple if statement `if ( $.browser.webkit )`. Regards

Comment: I actually don't agree that his solution is superior. Please refer this this [article](http://farukat.es/journal/2011/02/499-lest-we-forget-or-how-i-learned-whats-so-bad-about-browser-sniffing)

Comment: I actually switched answer to yours. I hadn't noticed the .focus() at the end. However, I don't understand why the `focus()` at the end solved it. How did it work? Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: The first call to focus is given a function as parameter. In jQuery, calls to event methods with a function as parameter will register that function as a callback. That means whenever the event occurs, the function will be called. When called without a parameter instead of registering a callback, the already registered callback functions will be invoked. Basically the last focus() calls the function you attached as an event handler in the first call to focus. Since the last focus is called when the page is done loading it will ensure the first function will be called after the page loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I got it now. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like:

```
if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
   countDown();
}
```

I think this will check if it's a webkit browser and then fire the countDown() event

Comment: UA sniffing is [not considered good style](http://farukat.es/journal/2011/02/499-lest-we-forget-or-how-i-learned-whats-so-bad-about-browser-sniffing) if it can be avoided (which it certainly can in this case).